# GAE Generating HTTP Error 400: Bad Request Traceback When Indexing URL from Twitch.tv API

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine

I seem to get this error when the application is deployed, however not when it is being served on localhost:

```
E 2012-08-21 18:03:46.914 HTTP Error 400: Bad Request Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py

E 2012-08-21 18:03:46.916 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 195, in Handle
```

The code that is generating this error is located here (please forgive the huge handler):

```
class Dashboard(MainHandler):

def check_if_live(self,b):
    url = ('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=%s' %b)
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    if contents.read() == '[]':
        return 'Offline'
    else:
        return 'Live'

def get(self, profile_id):
    u = User.by_name(profile_id.lower())
    if not u:
        self.redirect('/')
    elif self.user.name != profile_id:
        self.redirect('/profile/%s' %self.user.name)
    elif self.user and profile_id:
        current_user = self.user.name
        name1 = ''
        friend_name = ''
        team_imagee = ''
        key = ''
        monthss = ''
        yearss = ''
        dayss = ''
        countryss = ''
        team_imagee2 = ''
        imgs2 = ''
        imgs = ''
        key2 = ''
        name22 = ''
        name2 = ''
        streamss = ''
        streams_title = ''
        imgs  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
        imgs2  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", current_user)
        team_name  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teams WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
        team_images  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", profile_id)
        team_images2  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", current_user)
        friends  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Friends WHERE name =:1 order by added_date desc limit 10", profile_id)
        posts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Comments WHERE name_of_profile =:1 order by date_created desc", profile_id)
        name2 = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
        month = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
        day = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
        year = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
        country = db.GqlQuery("select * from User WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
        streams = db.GqlQuery("select * from Streams WHERE username =:1", current_user)
        for stream_title in streams:
            streams_title = stream_title.stream_title
        for stream in streams:
            streamss = stream.stream
        for months in month:
            monthss = months.month
        for countrys in country:
            countryss = countrys.country
        for days in day:
            dayss = days.day
        for years in year:
            yearss = years.year
        for clan in team_name:
                name1 = clan.team_name_anycase
        for clan in team_name:
                name2 = clan.team_name
        for image in team_images:
            team_imagee = image.key()
        for image2 in team_images2:
            team_imagee2 = image2.key()
        for img in imgs:
            key = img.key()
        for img2 in imgs2:
            key2 = img2.key()
        streamm = (streamss[(streamss.find('.tv/')+ 4):])
        check_if_life2 = self.check_if_live((streamss[(streamss.find('.tv/')+ 4):]))
        self.render('dashboard.html', streams = streams, stream_title2 = streamm, stream_title = streams_title, check_if_life = check_if_life2, team_name2 = name2,  imgs = imgs, team_img2 = team_imagee2, profile_image_posted = key2, posts = posts, profile_id = profile_id, country_var = countryss, day_var = dayss, year_var = yearss, month_var = monthss, current_user = current_user, friends = friends, team_img = team_imagee, team_name = name1, profile_image = key, username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, firstname = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country)
    else:
        self.redirect('/register')
```

This is specifically what is causing it:

```
    streamm = (streamss[(streamss.find('.tv/')+ 4):])
    check_if_life2 = self.check_if_live((streamss[(streamss.find('.tv/')+ 4):]))
```

Which makes use of the function 'check_if_live' at the top. As a total python noob, I can't for the life of me figure out why this error is being generated live and not on localhost.

EDIT:

I still cannot get the API to work. Its interesting how if you call the API in the address bar, for instances http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=nasltv, it works fine. But as soon as it touches app engine, it fails. I just need to index this API! Ah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there authentication involved in the API you are calling?  Maybe there is a redirection that stes a cookie.  IIRC the redirect behavior differs between prod and dev.

Comment: It seems to be an authentication issue. Would you mind me asking why a server would interpret a request from my local machine as something different from in this case, app engine?

Comment: It's probably not that the server can tell the difference.  It's probably that the urlfetch implementation in the SDK behaves differently on redirects than the production urlfetch implementation.  I recall answering questions about this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420795/urlfetch-redirected-into-an-infinite-loop-in-python -- maybe it has some hints.  Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288942/app-engines-urlfetch-http-get-works-locally-but-not-when-deployed-to-gae-on-a

Comment: Awesome. I'll do some reading. I've also sent an email to the support team for the API. Any who thank you very much! Cheers!

Comment: FWIW, App Engine always appends some fixed string to the User-Agent. If Twitch.tv doesn't like this, their problem. (OTOH we should probably do the same in the dev appserver.)