# A Most Frustrating Issue Between App Engine and the Twitch.tv API

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine

I'll make this as short and as clear as I can.

I have a simple application making a call to the twitch.tv api:

Example:

https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/nl_kripp

After it makes the call, it returns the data, (you could see that data if click the link above).

Ok so on to the issue. Here is my simple application created to just return that data on a web page:

```
import webapp2
import urllib2
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch



class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        url = ('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/nl_kripp')
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        self.response.out.write(result.content)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

When I run this application on my local machine, I see the returned data and everything is fine. However, when I deploy the application, I don't see any data at all.

That exact application is deployed at this URL:

http://urltestingsite.appspot.com/

A few people from app engine as well as twitch have tried to figure this out, and have had no luck at all. Please help me!!!

EDIT:

This is the same app, however making a call to another streaming sites API (own3d) and it works perfectly even when deployed:

```
import webapp2
import urllib2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        url = ('http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=10588')
        contents = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        self.response.out.write(contents.read())


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: the working example is http vs the non-working is https.  Is that relevant when trying to call from gae?

Comment: Wow, two months without success would indeed be frusterating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065320

Comment: The 400 issue was something else. But yea, i've been working on this for months on and off :P. I skipped over building the stream related app, however I now have to tackle it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about these particular sites, but it isn't uncommon for sites to blacklist either by user agent or by IP address, possibly because of some prior bad actor. If you're getting results when developing but not when deployed, I'd suspect the latter. Have you contacted the site?

Comment: Indeed I have. They claim that it isn't an issue on their end and that it shouldn't be blacklisted. Its quite strange...

Comment: Is there any way I could *cough cheat? Trick twitch.tv's API into thinking the call is coming from another IP or change the headers?

Comment: Were I in your position, I'd think very long and thoughtfully about whether I wanted to bounce the request off of a proxy. (I've gone through that thought process recently, and decided 'no', but that's me.)

Comment: It would be quite slow, which is why I hesitate to go that route... Especially when parsing 10+ calls to the API. Yea, I have no clue what to do here hahahhaa